# Why it occured "object has no attribute" error when Im defining a local function in a Python class?

Tags: python, class

I was writing a class, in which there's a method with local args.

```
class GlobalAssign:
    def __init__(self, seq1, seq2, d=-5, mismatch=-5, trans=-7):
        self.seq1 = list(seq1)
        self.seq2 = list(seq2)
        self.mismatch = mismatch
        self.d = d
        self.trans = trans
    def score(self, a, b):
        # score for any pair of bases
        pair = (str(a).capitalize(), str(b).capitalize())
        if pair in {('A', 'G'), ('G', 'A'), ('C', 'T'), ('T', 'C')}:
            return self.mismatch
        if pair in {('A', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('T', 'G'), ('G', 'T'),
                    ('A', 'T'), ('T', 'A'), ('C', 'G'), ('G', 'C')}:
            return self.trans
        elif a == '-' or b == '-':
            return self.d
```

And I run following codes in the terminal:

```
In [62]: test = GlobalAssign('agcg','gtat')

In [63]: test.score('a','g')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-f387aa9ccad8> in <module>
----> 1 test.score('a','g')

~/data/needleman.py in score(self, a, b)
     11     def score(self, a, b):
     12         # score for any pair of bases
---> 13         pair = (str(a).capitalize(), str(b).capitalize())
     14         if pair in {('A', 'G'), ('G', 'A'), ('C', 'T'), ('T', 'C')}:
     15             return self.mismatch

AttributeError: 'GlobalAssign' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I think **a** and **b** are local variables so I don't need to write self.a. But it raised this error and I'm a bit confused.Have been stuck for a while. Thanks if you could help me figure it out.

Comment: There's no obvious access of an attribute named `'a'` here. Did you override `GlobalAssign.__str__`? Or is it possible you have a stale `.pyc` file that's being executed instead of the code shown in the question?

Comment: Thanks! I deteled the pyc and open a new ipython kernel and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run your code in locally and it is working; it gives me the output of -5.

I have made some adjustment to your code in order to get all the cases:

```
class GlobalAssign:
    def __init__(self, seq1, seq2, d=-5, mismatch=-5, trans=-7):
        self.seq1 = list(seq1)
        self.seq2 = list(seq2)
        self.mismatch = mismatch
        self.d = d
        self.trans = trans
    def score(self, a, b):
        # score for any pair of bases
        pair = (str(a).capitalize(), str(b).capitalize())
        if pair in [('A', 'G'), ('G', 'A'), ('C', 'T'), ('T', 'C')]:
            return self.mismatch
        elif pair in [('A', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('T', 'G'), ('G', 'T'),
                    ('A', 'T'), ('T', 'A'), ('C', 'G'), ('G', 'C')]:
            return self.trans
        elif a == '-' or b == '-':
            return self.d
        else:
            print("Value not correct.")
            return None
```

Moreover i have removed the bracket `{}` and replaced with `[]` inside the `score` method.

Let me know if this help you.